# « Je serais si heureux que l'on ne m'entende qu'à mon signal, que l'on me croie sur silence » ?

Tags: sens, figure-de-style

> Je serais si heureux que l'on ne m'entende qu'à mon signal, que l'on
>   me croie sur silence.
>
> [ [Louis Scutenaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Scutenaire), [***Mes inscriptions***](https://books.google.com/books?id=M99AAQAAIAAJ&dq=editions%3AfkB_Az-g7NIC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=signal) (1943-1944, vol. 1) ]

---

Dans ce genre d'[*aphorisme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphorisme), on identifie aisément le jeu de mots avec *croire sur silence*/[sur parole](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/parole/58286/locution?q=sur%20parole#158153) : « *sans autre garantie que la bonne foi de celui qui donne sa parole* » (Larousse) :

- De quelle figure de style s'agit-il ([1](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_figures_de_style), [2](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&Th_id=286)) ?
- Y a-t-il d'autres figures de style employées dans la phrase ?
- Y a-t-il un sens particulier à donner à la première proposition, à la phrase ?

Comment: Peux-tu donner les phrases autour de celle-ci ? En lisant la phrase toute seule, c'est difficile de voir ce que l'auteur veut dire...

Comment: Tout à fait... Désolé.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there had been a full stop/period (or maybe even a semicolon) between the two clauses (and if I had been familiar with the word [and this applies to most of the others used below] prior to reading your links!), I might have attributed the fact that “Je serais si heureux” is not repeated in the second clause to “**l’asyndète**” (‘suppression des liens logiques et des conjonctions dans une phrase’ under ‘Figures de transformation non identique par effacement ou suppression’ of link 1).

The clauses being separated only by a comma, however, I see the omission of the second “Je serais si heureux”  more in line with “**l’ellipse [Rhétorique]**” (‘omettre un ou plusieurs éléments en principe nécessaires à la compréhension du texte, pour produire un effet de raccourci’, right below  “l’asyndète” on link 1’s list), and even more so with “**le zeugma [syntaxique]**” (four entries below “l’ellipse”),  which also involves avoiding the repetition of a common element, but not at the expense, as with “l’ellipse [Rhétorique],” of omitting an element that’s generally necessary to understand the text.

However, all of the above is probably rendered moot in light of my interpretation of the meaning of the sentence and its two propositions, because I feel that the author is actually saying the same thing in both clauses, which would make it more logical to choose from among “Figures de transformation identique” than from those (like the above) that are “non identique.”

With my interpretation (and non-literal translation) of both clauses (and therefore the entire sentence) being ... :

> “Trust me, I shall return, but for now please leave me to my
>   silence,”

... I’d argue that, both clauses being “identical,” this style reassembles “**l’expolition**” (under ‘Figures de transformation identique/Répétition morpho-syntaxique’ in link 1) in that it repeats the same ‘argument’ in different ways;
 and finally, to the (very limited) extent that two of something is enough to qualify as an accumulation, “**l’accumulation**” (also under ‘Figures de transformation identique/Répétition morpho-syntaxique’, about a dozen entries above “l’expolition”) could also describe this style.

Comment: *Parataxe* ( https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxe ) possible entre les deux phrases, à  cause de la `,` .

Answer (score 2):

- De quelle figure de style s'agit-il ?

Une [antilogie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilogie_(rh%C3%A9torique)) à mi-chemin entre une [antiphrase](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiphrase) et un [paradoxe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxe).

Comment: Peut-être plus proche des paradoxes pour la phrase complète, mais il y a aussi une répétition structurelle et sémantique relié par une `,` -- plusieurs styles semblent juxtaposés.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Je n'ai aucun talent pour la grammaire et le jargon des spécialistes, *surtout* que Papa Poule a donné des explications cohérentes :) ... Incapable dire si *surtout* est une hypotaxe, hypotaxe (anadiplose ???) qui de surcroît est un mot inconnu du correcteur orthographique du navigateur et de Grammalecte... Si je continue à pérorer ainsi, je vais me retrouver bien bien (palilogie ??? (encore un orphelin de dicos...)) seul... Absconse  synchise (autre mot inconnu de 99,99 % des francophones) dont je ne peux retenir que le vide.

Answer (score 1):

Hors contexte, la phrase peut porter à différentes interprétations. Voici donc la mienne, qui diffère des précédentes.

Tout d'abord, "croire sur silence" ne me semble pas si paradoxal qu'il ne semble. Pour moi, c'est un renforcement de "croire sur parole". Croire sur parole consiste en effet à accepter l'explication de quelqu'un sans que ce dernier n'apporte une preuve matérielle. Croire sur silence pourrait vouloir dire qu'il ne serait même pas nécessaire de fournir une explication.

Au vu de la seconde partie de la phrase, je suspecte une utilisation "d'entendre" dans le sens d'être auditionné (à un procès). Cela rejoindrait alors l'idée d'une innocence qui ne doit pas être défendue ( je serais si heureux si l'on ne m'accusait pas ).

Si l'on veut faire la chasse aux figures de styles :

petite allitération: si, signal, silence

amplification : on énumère 2 choses qui ont plus ou moins le même sens

parataxe : une conjonction de coordination (dans ce cas, "ET") est remplacée par une virgule.

Comment: « Pour moi, c'est un renforcement de "croire sur parole" », donc une *épanorthose* ? -- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89panorthose

Comment: l'épanorthose serait plutôt entre "que l'on ne m'entende qu'à mon signal (étape 1, où il faut parler )" et "que l'on me croie sur silence". Je ne sais pas à quelle figure de style "croire sur silence" peut être accrochée: il y en a à la fois trop et trop peu qui conviennent.

Answer (score 1):

- L'[*antithèse*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3241) (sens, contradiction) : entre le *signal* (un bruit) et le *silence*.
- La [*paronomase*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3234) (forme, prononciation) : *entendre* pour *attendre* (le signal).
- L'[*ellipse*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3213) (construction, sous-entendu): *signal (du départ)*.
- L'[*oxymore*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=3233) (sens, contradiction) : croire sur *silence*.

---

Plusieurs lectures sont possibles (voir autres réponses) et il peut y avoir récursivité. Ma version, versant dans l'ironie :

*Je serais si heureux qu'on attende que j'aie quitté pour m'entendre, et qu'on présume de mon innocence.*